# Azure application gateway listener

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I am trying to understand the difference between basic and multisite listener in Azure. I am going through Microsoft doc's but not getting the clear difference between them. Can any one explain it?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new listener, you choose between basic and multi-site.

1. If you want all of your requests (for any domain) to be accepted and forwarded to backend pools, choose basic. Learn how to create an application gateway with a basic listener.
2. If you want to forward requests to different backend pools based on the host header or hostname, choose multi-site listener, where you must also specify a hostname that matches with the incoming request. This is because Application Gateway relies on HTTP 1.1 host headers to host more than one website on the same public IP address and port.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-overview#listeners

also this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#types-of-listeners